# StatusCode in IHttpModule is always 200?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpmodule, ihttpmodule

I have an custom `IHttpModule` that handels all available events and logs the `HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode` to a file.

My `web.config` does not contain any other module in `<httpModules>` so all errors are promoted to the browser.

Although the Browsers shows a 404, the log file is full of 200 (Ok) entries and not a single 404.

What am I missing?

---

### Update

An Url ending with `.aspx` does have a `404` StatusCode in the `PreSendRequestHeaders` event,
but Urls wending with `.pdf` for example show StatusCode `200` in all events?!

Answer (score 0):

Is your module actually running when there's a 404?

Have you attached a debugger to the application with a breakpoint in the module - does it get hit at that when you request a non-existant .aspx page? Does it get hit when you request a non-existant file or directory?

Depedning on the set-up of IIS, it's possible that ASP.NET isn't getting a look in with these errors - it's not going to handle a request for somepage.html for example, or missing.gif.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the .aspx. I updated the question. Module is running: it logs a bunch of "Eventname+Status+Url" lines.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it casting the current exception in the handler in HttpException. Then, you can get the Http error code.

```
Exception exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
if (httpException != null)
{
    int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
}
```

Source : http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/57/getting-the-correct-http-status-codes-out-of-asp.net-custom-error-pages

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party. Try removing preCondition="managedHandler" in web.config for your module